# Apple pie making...how to add the crumble crust on top of the mound of raw apples?

Tags: crust, apple-pie

We made two apple pies for Thanksgiving. Both recipes called for adding a mixture on top of your apples to create a crumbly top crust for the pie.

Mixture one involved butter, flour, and sugar. (I cut the dry ingredients into the butter)
Mixture two involved melted butter, crushed graham crackers, crushed walnuts, and sugar

There was about 2 cups of each mixture.

Mixture one was stickier and had larger chunks due to the solid butter that we were working with. It was easier to add to the top of the mound of apples.

However, we found that it was almost impossible to pour mixture two on top of one of the pies. We couldn't contain all of that on top of the mound of apples. We essentially just mixed most of it into the apples and then poured the remaining on top for the crust.

Are there any suggestions for making crumple crust for apple pies? I guess one idea could be  to add the crumble crust after the apples has reduced down a bit during baking.

Comment: Were the apples in the 2nd pie really mounded up?  Is that why the topping didn't want to stay on the apples?

Comment: @KristinaLopez, yes...the apples were really mounded up. But they all cooked down and the final result was a fairly standard looking pie.

Comment: It's the 'melted' that's wrong there. You should use cool butter for crumbles. The idea is that the flour should coat the butter, but that the butter and flour don't become completely mixed.

Comment: Maybe you just needed a slightly deeper dish?

Comment: @BaffledCook ... +1 for suggesting not to melt the butter for the second crumble. Perhaps I can melt, mix and let it solidify again?

Comment: No, that's not how it's done. The butter has to be cool, otherwise it'll mix with the flour. You want to coat the butter with flour. ["It is important that the butter is cold, or you will end up making more of a dough than a crumble."](http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/plumcrumble_89925)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the crumb recipe on the Epicurious [Website](http://m.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/Cinnamon-Crumble-Apple-Pie-108650), the crumb mixture should be the texture of wet sand and then packed down on the mound of filling:

> 1 cup all purpose flour
>
> 1/2 cup sugar
>
> 1/4 cup (packed) golden brown sugar
>
> 1 1/2 teaspoons ground cinnamon
>
> 1/2 teaspoon salt
>
> 6 tablespoons chilled unsalted butter, cut into 1/2-inch cubes
>
> Blend first 5 ingredients in processor. Add chilled butter cubes;
>   using on/off turns, cut in until mixture resembles wet sand.
>
> (After mounding the filling in the crust, pack topping over and around apples. Bake pie on baking
>   sheet in pre-heated 400-degree oven, until topping is golden, about 40 minutes (cover top with foil
>   if browning too quickly). Reduce oven temperature to 350°F. Bake until
>   apples in center are tender when pierced and filling is bubbling
>   thickly at edges, about 45 minutes longer. Cool until warm, about 1
>   hour. Serve with ice cream.

Comment: I accepted the answer because I think the technique of packing the topping around the apples is the key. I think I needed to pack it with my hands. I was spooning and pouring the loose mixture on top of the mound. :)

Comment: @milesmeow, thanks! ...and I learned about mounding the filling while researching this answer.